# Telegraf - how to run bash script with a flag?

Tags: bash, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I am trying to configure telegraf to run bash script with a flag.

For example:

```
[[inputs.exec]] ## Commands array
  commands = [ 
    "/tmp/test.sh", 
  ]
```

That works fine, but when I modify it to:

```
[[inputs.exec]] 
  ## Commands array 
  commands = [ 
    "/tmp/test.sh -r", 
  ]
```

It looks like telegraf is ignoring the '-r' flag.

What is wrong?

Comment: Maybe your script do not handle the key propperly

Comment: Running that script with flag from command line works fine.

Comment: try using `"/tmp/test.sh", "-r"`,

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
  commands = [
 "/bin/bash -c '/tmp/test.sh -r'"
]
```

Best.